# Namespace conflict between blazor app and c# project classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have two projects in my solution one is a client side web assembly Blazor project and the other is a c# project in which I keep my DTOs and other classes.

The following is a simplified overview of the structure of the blazor app:

Web

- Shared

  - MainLayout.razor

I import the above asd follows in a _imports.razor file:
@using Web.Shared;

The above works fine.

Now, is the structure of the c# Project:

Shared

- Dtos

  - Response

    - Attachment

      - AttachmentDto.cs

AttachmentDto.cs is as follows:

```
namespace Shared.Dtos.Response.Attachments
{
    public class AttachmentDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
   }
}
```

therefore it uses the namespace: Shared.Dtos.Response

Here is where the problem arises.  When I attempt to reference Shared.Dtos.Response.Attachments.AttachmentDto in my blazor app, it is attempting to resolve it Web.Shared uder whcih it fails to find AttachmentDto and therefore throws an error.

I have tried using an alias in my imports file and also where I ever wish to use AttachmentDto, but the alias suffers from the same ambiguity issue:

Below is my usage:

List.razor.cs:

```
using ResponseContext = Shared.Dtos.Response;

namespace Web.Pages.Transactions 
{
    private List<ResponseContext.Attachment.AttachmentDto> TransactionAttachments { get; set; } = new();    

}
```

List.razor:

```
<AttachmentsList Attachments="@TransactionAttachments"></AttachmentsList>
```

Attachments.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using ResponseContext = Shared.Dtos.Response;

namespace Web.Components
{
    public partial class AttachmentsList
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<ResponseContext.Attachment.AttachmentDto> Attachments { get; set; } = default!;

    }
}
```

In the above line, it still seems to try resolve Shared.Dtos under Web.Shared. The error is:

```
The type or namespace name 'Dtos' does not exist in the namespace 'Web.Shared' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Web 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Shared.Dtos.Response.Attachment.AttachmentDto>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Web.Shared.Dtos.Response.Attachment.AttachmentDto>'    Web
```

I also tried prepending global:: to the reference but that also did not help.

How can this ambiguity be resolved?  Is it possible without refactoring the namespaces / folder names?

Comment: Not really reproducible. Using 'Shared' as a root name is very questionable (Shared inside what?) but VS is not confused and adds `@using global::Shared.Attachments;` to resolve it.

Comment: It should of ourse have been `MyProject.Shared.Attachments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible without refactoring the namespaces / folder names?

Everything is possible, but patching a poorly designed solution will only lead to more issues down the road.

You don't need to intrinsically tie your directory structure to your namespace.  In large projects with lots of sub-directories it may get tedious if you did.  Collapsing sub-directories into the same namespace often works.  It all depends on how you want to organise your folder structure and files.

You need a root namespace for your solution and then organise everything as sub namespaces from that.  `MyApp` would normally be your root.

In your shared project you can either have a single namespace or group your classes into just a few logical units.  For example:

*MyApp.Data* for the all the data stuff in your shared project.

So `AttachmentDto` is declared as:

```
namespace MyApp.Data;

public class AttachmentDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can also set the namespace for Razor files explicitly like this:

```cs
@page "/"
@namespace MyApp.WASM
```

Personally I would move away from calling your library `Shared`.  `MyApp.Shared` if you must use shared, otherwise something like `MyApp.Data` or similar.

Comment: Ignoring the normal rules for namespaces/folders is very bad advice. In large projects it would be very tedious to _change_ (and maintain) namespaces manually.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to arrange your folder structure.   You shouldn't be silly, but you don't need to strictly adhere. For instance, check the folder for `InputBase`.  It's folder location is `src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs`, and it's namespace is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components: the namespace only loosely resembles the folder structure.  However I have reworked my answer to reflect the above view, there are those that will take my comment and think being extreme is OK [which wasn't my intent in the comment]!

Comment: Not the best of examples because Blazor was moved from its own repo to  a place in the already crowded asp.net core repo. So, the `src` folders don't count and then the only deviation here is not doubling the `Components` part. From there on everything seems to follow the rules normally.

Comment: Two further black and white examples, one for and one against.  MudBlazor doesn't stick, with lots of sub-folders.  Radzen does, with one almighty great folder of source files.  Thank goodness we live in a non-monchrome dictator ruled world!